# strange hashing issue using pip hash

Tags: python, hash

I want to install some python packages using pip but cannot as every file downloaded produces the same hash, which then fails comparison in pips security check.

After playing around, I see that every file I download using curl from files.pythonhosted will hash to the same value. I've tested this with a python script like so:

```
curl http://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/80/b06ce333aabba7ab1b6a41ea3c4e46970ceb396e705733480a2d47a7f74b/Django-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl -o django.whl
```

```
import hashlib

hasher = hashlib.sha256()
BLOCKSIZE = 65536

def hash_stuff(file):
    with open(file, 'rb') as afile:
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    print(hasher.hexdigest())

hash_stuff("pynvim.tar.gz")
hash_stuff("opencv.tar.gz")
hash_stuff("django.whl")
```

which outputs:

```
➜  ~ python pythonhash.py
c77ab57a36e39ce205ca2327a3edd10399f4d78a3be91e80d845a1b97c29b7d6
ea75572349ed10da0f3224398737fd08352ae10e6f3c571345feb971e080a276
9e31adaf584633587df90d7be36e2fb287c7344eaa4bb23d619f4bdaa19a67d0
```

if I modify the order of the `hash_stuff` function like so (note the ordering is different):

```
hash_stuff("django.whl")
hash_stuff("opencv.tar.gz")
hash_stuff("pynvim.tar.gz")
```

the output does not change!

```
➜  ~ python pythonhash.py
c77ab57a36e39ce205ca2327a3edd10399f4d78a3be91e80d845a1b97c29b7d6
ea75572349ed10da0f3224398737fd08352ae10e6f3c571345feb971e080a276
9e31adaf584633587df90d7be36e2fb287c7344eaa4bb23d619f4bdaa19a67d0
```

If I reset the `hasher` object I get the first hash `c77ab57` three times like so

```
def hash_stuff(file):
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    BLOCKSIZE = 65536
    with open(file, 'rb') as afile:

-----
➜  ~ python pythonhash.py
c77ab57a36e39ce205ca2327a3edd10399f4d78a3be91e80d845a1b97c29b7d6
c77ab57a36e39ce205ca2327a3edd10399f4d78a3be91e80d845a1b97c29b7d6
c77ab57a36e39ce205ca2327a3edd10399f4d78a3be91e80d845a1b97c29b7d6
```

I've written the same test in ruby and getting the same results..

```
require 'digest'

puts Digest::SHA256.hexdigest File.read "django.whl"
puts Digest::SHA256.hexdigest File.read "opencv.tar.gz"
puts Digest::SHA256.hexdigest File.read "pynvim.tar.gz"
```

As a sanity check, I've tested hashing some local files and they produce the same hash consistently, regardless of ordering.

- How can the ordering of execution effect the hash?
- erm, files.pythonhosted doesn't even have a proper ssl certificate.. - can I even trust this host?
- What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: you need to reset the hash! hash functions keep their state (after calling `digest`). that is why the order matters.

Comment: If the files produce the same hash (once you're properly resetting it between files), then the overwhelmingly likely explanation is that they *have the same contents*.  Take an actual look at what's really in these files - my guess is that something went wrong with your `curl` command, and all they contain is an error message of some sort (identical for each file).

Comment: If I reset the hash, then all files (which are all different) produce the same hash: `c77ab57a36e39ce205ca2327a3edd10399f4d78a3be91e80d845a1b97c29b7d6`

Comment: yep @jasonharper you're right! (I didn't notice this at first because of the .gz)any idea what would be wrong with the original `pip install django` command and why it produces the same file regardless of package?

Comment: oh god, I think my provider is blocking files.pythonhosted because of the cert issue ` <h3 class="heading heading--3">
                                Secure Net ha bloqueado el contenido.
                            </h3>
                            <p id="domain-text" class="grey--text">
                                El contenido de files.pythonhosted.org se ha considerado inseguro. Secure Net te recomienda cerrar esta página y seguir navegando.
                            </p>
`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my internet provider was blocking the content due to files.pythonhosted having a self signed ssl certificate.

the reason the hash was the same for all files was because I was getting an error html page (doh..) thanks @jasonharper for the pointer!